# Flask session cookie reverting

Tags: flask, session, session-cookies

I am sure I am probably being stupid but struggling to wrap my head around this one.

I have a flask website and I am setting up a checkout page for it so users can add their items to the cart etc.  Everything was going great, I was able to add items to the cart, get a total etc (using sessions) however when I have tried to implement the ability for users to update the cart on the checkout page, when my form posts, the session data only survives the initial load.  The print statement shows the data I am collecting is fine, and the session cookie is set initially, as everything updates, however the moment I then change page, it reverts to whatever it was before I made the update.

```
@views.route("/shopping-cart", methods=['GET','POST'])
def to_cart():
    clear_cart = 'views.to_clear_cart'
    if 'shopping' in session:
        shopping_list = session['shopping']
        sum_list = []
        for quantity, price in shopping_list.values():
            sum_list.append(quantity * price)
        total = sum(sum_list)

        if request.method == "POST":
            new_quantity = int(request.form.get('quantity'))
            product_id = request.form.get('issue')
            unit_price = int(request.form.get('price'))
            print(new_quantity, product_id, unit_price)
            shopping_list[f'{product_id}'] = [new_quantity, unit_price]
            
            return redirect(url_for('views.to_cart'))

        return render_template("cart.html",
        shopping_list=shopping_list,
        total=total,
        clear_cart=clear_cart,
        )

        
    else:
        return render_template("cart.html",
            clear_cart=clear_cart
        )
```

I just do not really understand why it is not updating as from what I can tell, the code is running fine, and it does update, but then the session cookie just reverts itself to whatever it was before (using browser side cookies for this for testing).

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

After much confusion as everything seemed to be working absolutely fine after I rewrote this in about 5 different ways and printed half the app in the console, I finally found the answer and it is indeed me being an idiot.

It turns out if you modify a value in place rather than creating or deleting it does not automatically save the session state and you just need to state explicitly that it has been modified.

Turns out the answer was as simple as this line of code.

```
session.modified = True
```